# Laravel - Multi company scopes

Tags: php, laravel

I am quite new to Laravel, but get most of the basics by now.

Currently, I build an application, where multiple companies each get an account that represents their main user, let's call him CompanyAdmin. 
This user is allowed to create new users **for this company** and able to view all quotes from the company.

The newly created users, call them CompanyEmployee, can not create new users and only view the quotes they created themselves, as well as creating new quotes.

Now there is of course one SuperAdmin, which sits on the other side of the table. He views all quotes from all companies, is able to do create users as he pleases and can accept/edit quotes.

My current approach to do this would be to attach a user_id to all quotes and attach the users to a company, as well as giving them a role. 
All the logic would take place in the controller, where I would check the role of the user and therefore read/save only the quotes, the user is able to edit.

However, it feels very dirty to do so and sounds like a lot of effort to maintain. If you would e.g. make another role for an employee of the SuperAdmin, you would need to change every controller.

I could not find a way to define the access rights per role per model, so when I call Quotes::all() it only retrieves the legal ones (same goes for saving of course).

Please guide me to a Laravel feature (or even package, but I have not used one before) that helps me get things done.

Looking forward to possible solutions that lead to low maintainance. 
Best regards!

Comment: have a look at role-based permissions: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust basically you create roles, and then you create permissions, then assign permissions to those roles, and then assign a role to a user. You can do `$user->hasRole('superadmin')` or do `$user->can('edit-quotes')`

Comment: Thank you! However, the focus is more on the company based view, where the users are attached to. The permission is then set within the company.

Comment: you can combine this with what Nikola Gavric has mentioned below and use middleware/guards to allow access to company views for only those who belong to the company and use permissions to check what actions they can perform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For authenticating different types of users and protecting group of routes that particular type can access you can use [`guards`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#authentication-quickstart), for authorizing `CRUD` actions you can use [`FormRequest`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#creating-form-requests), I think you have everything you need under these 2 links, ofcourse you will need to read up on these, this is a good starting point. As for tables, you can have these:

users, roles, companies, user_role, user_company

And models:

User, Role, Company

Comment: I read more on it and this appears to be the perfect solution. Especially the FormRequest makes life a lot easier in my case with it's authorisation. Will accept your answer!

Answer (score 2):

from the doc

> In addition to providing authentication services out of the box,
>   Laravel also provides a simple way to authorize user actions against a
>   given resource. Like authentication, Laravel's approach to
>   authorization is simple, and there are two primary ways of authorizing
>   actions: gates and policies.

Laravel has 2 concepts called Gates and Policies which we can inject it on models,(specially Gates), So when ever the queries are called upon the Model, the Gates make sure that the user has appropriate permissions.

You can read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization)